# exit a nested loop in excel

Tags: loops, excel, vba

i have a loop in a macro i'm writing of the following structure:

there are two worksheets in this book. raw data (hence the endpointData variable) and a G/L (General ledger) sheet (hence the endpointGL variable)

there are three `for` loops in this function:

(1) the first loop iterates through each record in the raw data file. 
 (2) the second loop iterates through the verified matches from `REGEXP` (a regular expression search) and 
 (3) the third loop goes through the G/L and finds a corresponding match and puts (using: `PUT_DATA_RANGE`) that data into the appropriate spot.

Here's sort of what i'm getting at:

psuedocode:

```
For i = 2 To endpointData

    If SOME_TEST = True Then
        Set MATCHES = REGEXP.EXECUTE()
        For Each myMatch In MATCHES
            For j = 1 To endpointGL
                If myMatch.value = SOME_CONDITION Then
                    PUT_DATA_RANGE
                    Exit For
                ElseIf myMatch.value <> SOME_CONDITION Then
                    MsgBox ("there might be a problem")
                    ' EXIT BOTH LOOPS HERE

                    ' write handler code
            Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next i
```

now you'll notice that i have a few comments to myself. if the third loops finds no match in the G/L the code currently interrupts to notify the user. but that message box `MsgBox("there might be a problem")` is looped through along with the third loop. how do i get excel to exit BOTH loops and bring the FIRST for loop to the next availabe record in the raw data?

by the way, i've tried exiting it with an `Exit For` but that doesn't seem to work exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two options.

1) Use a series of booleans to check if the outer loops should continue

2) Use a goto statement to exit from the inner loop directly back to the main procedure

In this situation, the goto might not be so bad since you aren't jumping to a completely different part of the code. Just document it well...

Comment: some sort of iterator needs to be implemented too so that it doesn't continue where it left off. right?

Comment: I don't think so. When it starts the loops the next time, they should reinitialize their counters. I would have to try it though.

Comment: this is one way to solve it. look at the implementation of an ExitLoop boolean value. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10539817/778694