# insert rows after a data point changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
This1    GH
This2    GH
This3    GH
This4    BR
This5    BR
This6    VB
```

when the data point changes, i.e. "GH" to "BR" I want excel to insert a line break. so that the finalized data looks like this.

```
This1    GH
This2    GH
This3    GH

This4    BR
This5    BR

This6    VB
```

any idea how this would be done? i think that a negative iterating for loop would work. but i don't know how excel would handle row manipulation in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to do it (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("A:B").Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlCount, TotalList:=Array(2), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

        Set aCell = .Cells.Find(What:=" Count", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            .Rows(aCell.Row).ClearContents
            Do While ExitLoop = False
                Set aCell = .Cells.FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    .Rows(aCell.Row).ClearContents
                Else
                    ExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        End If

        .Cells.RemoveSubtotal
    End With
End Sub
```

I am assuming that Row 1 has headers.

**MACRO IN ACTION**

[image]

Comment: +1 I thought about subtotals but wasn't sure about how to implement it.

Comment: incidentally this also answer this qusetion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536730/exit-a-nested-loop-in-excel

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your spreadsheet does not have thousands of lines you can use this (quick and dirty) code:

```
Sub doIt()

  Dim i As Long

  i = 2
  While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    If Cells(i, 2) <> Cells(i - 1, 2) Then
      Rows(i).Insert
      i = i + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: "Assuming your spreadsheet does not have thousands of lines" why would this matter? simply because of the time it would take??

Comment: Yes it would be slow if it had to insert more than a few hundred rows. In which case Siddhart's solution would be better.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above 'slow' excel problem, don't forget to disable the application.screenupdating , it will improve speed in any macro with 5000%

```
Sub doIt()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim i As Long

  i = 2
  While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
  If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
     Rows(i).Insert

     i = i + 1
  End If
  i = i + 1
 Wend
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```